# Are there any countries that will not allow entry with a Japanese visa stamp in my passport?

Tags: legal, japan, borders, passport-stamps, eu-citizens

I'm aware that you might have trouble for example entering Israel with an Egyptian visa stamp in your passport. Ignoring any COVID-19 related restrictions etc. are there any countries I might have trouble entering with a Japanese tourist visa stamp (sticker) in my (EU country) passport?

Comment: In my experience it was always an issue to enter a muslim country with an Israeli stamp in your passport.  Which is why Israel gave you the option of getting your stamp on a separate pice of paper.

Comment: @PeterM even an Israeli stamp is much less of an issue now. Israeli citizens can even enter UAE visa free starting from this year.

Comment: @JonathanReez According to my passport I've nerve been to Israel and if anyone claims they saw me there then they are lying.  And the pics of me at various monuments and tourist attractions are all obviously deep fakes.

Comment: I can't imagine of any... Did you have any potential candidates in your mind?

Answer (score 7):

> are there any countries I might have trouble entering with a Japanese tourist visa stamp (sticker) in my (EU country) passport?

No. (e.g. see the [UK list of incompatible countries](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/873183/Additional_Passports_v3__for_DAP_release__.pdf#page=7&zoom=100,92,928) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210203120212/https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/873183/Additional_Passports_v3__for_DAP_release__.pdf#page=7&zoom=100,92,928))).

Comment: Technically this is not correct information as the UK is no longer an EU country.  However the OP may be a UK citizen with an unexpired EU passport.

Comment: @PeterM either way the answer is still no.